# Recursively get all the files and dirs they are located in

Tags: linux, bash, macos

Trying to run a script that will fetch all directories, and files containing these directories, and logs data onto a .CSV file.

So, if I were to have structure like:
mainDir.dir -> [sub1.dir -> file01.png, sub2.dir -> file02.png]
, I would get a CSV of

- dir; file
- sub1; file01.png
- sub2; file02.png

This is the script I currently have

```
for dir in */ .*/ ; 
do
    for entry in $dir
    do
        path="$entry"
        empty=""
        file="${$dir/$empty}"
        echo -e "$dir;$file;" >> file.csv
    done

done
```

Comment: What's wrong with `ls -AR` ?

Comment: Using the output of ls to get filenames is a bad idea. It can lead to malfunctioning and even dangerous scripts. This is because a filename can contain any character except / and the nullcharacter, and ls does not use either of those characters as delimiters, so if a filename has a space or a newline, you will get unexpected results.

Comment: You could also look at `find`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need more than one level deep, this seems to work

```
for i in **/*; do echo $i | tr / \; ; done >> file.csv
```

Comment: Can you explain? How can I replace now the file02.png with something like my-url.com/pictures/file02.png? I see that $i is the dir, but where is the file name?

Comment: After expansion you get "any file inside a directory". Inside the loop you get the full relative path, if that makes sense: 'sub1.dir/file01.png', tr replaces the slash with a semicolon

Comment: @Alex what do you want to do exactly ? Process the csv ? In pure bash  or other language ?

Answer (score 1):

`find` is useful for processing many files recursively.

**Command**

`find . -type f -execdir sh -c "pwd | tr -d '\n' >> ~/my_file.csv; echo -n ';' >> ~/my_file.csv; echo {} | sed -e 's/^\.\///' >> ~/my_file.csv" \;`

Note:  make sure you do not give a relative path to the output CSV file.  execdir changes the working directory (and that is what makes pwd work).

**Breakdown**

`find . -type f`  find all files recursively starting here

`-execdir sh -c "pwd | tr -d '\n' >> ~/my_file.csv; echo -n ';' >> ~/my_file.csv;` For each file, execute in its directory `pwd`.  Strip the newline and add directory name to output.  Also add a semicolon, again with no newline.

`echo {} | sed -e 's/^\.\///' >> ~/my_file.csv" \;` Append filename to output. This time, leave newline, but by default `find` will place the `./` in front of the filename. The `sed` here removes it.